# Structured Streaming (Spark 2.3.0) cannot write to Parquet file sink when submitted as a job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm consuming from Kafka and writing to parquet in EMRFS. Below code works in `spark-shell`:

```scala
val filesink_query = outputdf.writeStream
  .partitionBy(<some column>)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", <some path in EMRFS>)
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/ingestcheckpoint")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10.seconds))
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
  .start
```

SBT is able to package the code without errors. When the .jar is sent to spark-submit, the job is accepted and stays in running state forever without writing data to HDFS.

There is no ERROR in the .inprogress log

Some posts suggest that a large watermark duration can cause it, but I have not set a custom watermark duration.

Comment: running in the same problem. have you found a solution?

Comment: We abandoned EMR for unrelated reasons, but if I remember correctly I wrote to local disk instead, and copied in batches to S3 for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I can write to parquet using Pyspark, I put you my code in case that will be useful:

```
stream = self.spark.readStream \
          .format("kafka") \
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", self.kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
          .option("subscribe", self.topic) \
          .option("startingOffsets", self.startingOffsets) \
          .option("max.poll.records", self.max_poll_records) \
          .option("auto.commit.interval.ms", self.auto_commit_interval_ms) \
          .option("session.timeout.ms", self.session_timeout_ms) \
          .option("key.deserializer", self.key_deserializer) \
          .option("value.deserializer", self.value_deserializer) \
          .load()

self.query = stream \
        .select(col("value")) \
        .select((self.proto_function("value")).alias("value_udf")) \
        .select(*columns,
                date_format(column_time, "yyyy").alias("date").alias("year"),
                date_format(column_time, "MM").alias("date").alias("month"),
                date_format(column_time, "dd").alias("date").alias("day"),
                date_format(column_time, "HH").alias("date").alias("hour"))

query = self.query \
            .writeStream \
            .format("parquet") \
            .option("checkpointLocation", self.path) \
            .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour") \
            .option("path", self.path) \
            .start()
```

Also, you need to run the code in that way: `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 <code>`